# ES6: Module '"mongoose"' has no default export

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

Using ES6 Imports & Exports I feel like I should be able to declare the import as
`import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from 'mongoose';` but I get the error `Module '"mongoose"' has no default export.`

The below does work but it clearly isn't the right way to go about this import. The export default id like to remove too.

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Schema, Document } from 'mongoose';

export interface IUser extends Document {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

const UserSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true }
});

export default mongoose.model<IUser>('User', UserSchema);
```

And then im using it with

```
import UserModel, { IUser } from '../models/example'
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

class User {
  static register = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const alreadyRegistered = await UserModel.findOne({email}).exec();
    if (!alreadyRegistered) {
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password,10);
        if (!hashedPassword) {
          res.status(500).send({ message: "Failed to encrypt your password" });
        } else {
          const user = new UserModel(<IUser>{email:email, password:hashedPassword});
          const saved = await user.save();
          if (!saved) {
            res.status(500).send({ message: "Failed to register you" });
          } else {
            res.status(200).send({ message: "You are now registered" });
          }
        }
    } else {
      res.status(400).send({ message: "You have already registered" });
    }
  };
}

export {User}
```

Answer (score 14):

I came across this issue and fixed it by adding the following to `tsconfig.json`

```
"esModuleInterop": true
```

Then I could import as normal
`import mongoose from 'mongoose'`

Answer (score 8):

Try This

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true }
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

2nd Way -

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

type UserSchema = IUser & mongoose.Document;

const User = mongoose.model<UserSchema>('User', new mongoose.Schema({
        email  : { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
          password: { type: String, required: true }
    }));
export = User;
```

Comment: the line `mongoose.model<IUser>('User', UserSchema);` now gives an error of `Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments.`

Comment: Use module.exports if you are using express     module.exports= mongoose.model<IUser>('User', UserSchema);             and also import IUser in same file

Comment: I dont quite understand please could you update your answer to reflect this?

Comment: Check once the answer then let me know

Comment: the firstone gives an error of `Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments.` the second option gives an error `An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements.`If I dont export the interface IUser then i get the error `Cannot find name 'IUser'`

Comment: Now Check the first one and tell me you are creating a mongo collection for email and password.

Comment: I've updated the question with the function that uses the model, updating the model as show in your first example then causes errors in the function that uses the model

Comment: My first example is fine just directly import it on other function and use the User.

Comment: Is it just not possible with ES6 imports and exports?

Comment: Yes it's possible

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,` in `tsconfig.json` file.

Reference: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter/issues/8#issuecomment-301265017

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are compiling the typescript but it should work just fine with the defaults set in `tsconfig.json` file.

- generate `tsconfig.json` in your project's root directory by running `tsc --init` (as mentioned, you can use defaults for this to work with target set even to `es5`)
- now you can run `tsc -w` or `ts-node index.ts` or however you prefer to build/run your code

Note that the `index.ts` file must be either in your project's root or you will need to specify the path in the `tsconfig.json` (the `rootDir` options which is commented out by default and uses path relative to the `tsconfig` file).

Also note that if you are running `tsc -w` or some other command that compiles/runs the code from some other directory than the one where `tsconfig.json` is located, you will need to provide a path to it, i.e. `tsc -p path_to_config -w`

Answer (score 0):

I Have the same issue I noticed that I missed the `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 0):

```
import { model, Schema } from 'mongoose';
...
export default model<IUser>('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.